# What is a WINEPREFIX?

Tags: wine

I have searched a bit but cannot find a clear-cut, precise answer. I believe I'm not the only one looking for a clear definition.

- What is a Wineprefix?
- What is its function?
- What is a "clean" Wineprefix?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WINEPREFIX` is an [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

It defines where Wine looks for its configuration and files, in essence where it puts its `C:` drive.

By default it is `$HOME/.wine`.

Some programs require very specific configurations and some people will use a specific prefix for different programs.

See the [Wine wiki for Wineprefixes](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Wineprefixes) for details on how to do so and various options.

Answer (score 4):

A Wineprefix is like a small windows system that is run through wine.  A clean Wineprefix is a brand new one that does not have any programs installed in it or settings changed.  What you can do is have a separate Wineprefix for every program you install on wine to make removal easier and to prevent conflict.  I think that is what Winetricks does.  The default one is stored in your home folder in `.wine`.