# How do I set scaling in Wine?

Tags: wine, scaling

When I use regular or fractional scaling, content generated by Wine does not scale. This looks particularly bad under fractional scaling because the Wine content takes up relatively less of the screen.

**No scaling, 125% scaling, 200% scaling. Adjusted for perceived height.**

[image] [image] [image]

In other software that does not honor desktop scaling I have found an independent scaling setting for that software. (e.g. [layout.css.devPixelsperPx in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487032/)).

How can I set scaling in Wine?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To set scaling in Wine you need to adjust the Wine DPI setting. You can find this is Wine Configuration (`winecfg`) under the Graphics tab. In this example under 125% fractional desktop scaling, setting the Wine screen resolution to 240dpi scales Wine content appropriately (for my tastes).

You will need to configure this setting for each wineprefix.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve some edge cases, see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1656143 for a more involved (untested) solution.

Comment: what do you mean for each wine prefix? after I set the setting the windows app is still running at normal dpi.

Comment: @Kleajmp I'm not enough of a wine expert to give a succinct answer, perhaps these links will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/956244/

Comment: @Kleajmp I'd also suggest trying with a simple app (notepad?) first, just to confirm it's working

Comment: "You will need to configure this setting for each wineprefix." // How?